# Custom callback for RailsAdmin::MainController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I have an `role` column in my `User` model and I want to prevent someone from accessing the rails_admin routes if they don't have an `admin` flag. Since the `RailsAdmin::MainController` doesn't inherit from `ApplicationController` I'm not sure how I can insert this check before the view loads.

I'm not keen on creating a new `Admin` model as per the devise docs. I would like to use the same user account.

Does anyone have any suggestions? =)

Answer (score 1):

You can define from which controller your rails admin will inherit by defining it in the config/initializers/rails_admin.rb file like this:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.parent_controller = '::ApplicationController'
end
```

And also i recommend using a gem to handle authorization, cancancan or pundit will handle nicely your use case.

Comment: thanks heaps for the answer :) Since then I have decided to separate my admin app from the main application to keep things more maintainable. I haven't spun that instance up yet, but will give this a go then :)